# No Index Filter pages

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, layered-navigation, filter, search, seo

How do I set noindex for the filter pages?

I have a little dupilicate content issue and no have an ajax navigation but I want to set noindex follow fpr the pages to get them out of google,

Any ideas how to add the meta tag to these pages ?

example URL `www.example.com/furniture/wardrobes.html?cat=34&price=asc`

I have used google Parameters to crawl NO URLs with the parameters and enabled Rel= Can to orginal pages

Thanks.

Comment: would this code in Head.phtml work ?

 <?php 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$needle = "?";
if (strpos($url, $needle)) : ?>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Answer for this can be found here:
http://doejo.com/blog/magento-how-to-add-noindex-nofollow-robots-meta-tag-or-change-meta-title-or-description-on-certain-pages/

You need the correct layout handle, for layered navigation use this code **(be careful, this adds NOINDEX to unfiltered pages too!)**:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
   </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, When this is implemeted would you still use URL parameters in WMT and use NO URLS with the parameters that are causing issues ? or let google crawl pages with "cat=" and "mode=" etc ?

Comment: I dont know what you are meaning. What os WMT? What is "NO URLS"?

Comment: Arrr... Webmaster tools in google, You can set your parameters not to be craweled (no Urls) so in this case i told it not to crawl parameters like mode= and cat= and limit= .... But in this instance do i want this as will the bots still be able to see the noindex,follow tag ?

Comment: If anyone access the page, he/she will see noindex,follow - the crawler too. Maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: Doesnt this add NOINDEX to the "unfilters" (read; original/canonical) category page too? I think one would like to have NOINDEX on the category pages only where a filter is active

Comment: good point, yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        <observers>
            <noindex>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>YOURMODULE/observer</class>
                <method>changeRobots</method>
            </noindex>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
</events>
```

Observer.php

```
public function changeRobots($observer){
    if($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
        $uri = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        if(stristr($uri,"?")): // looking for a ?
            $layout       = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
            $product_info = $layout->getBlock('head');
            $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="head"><action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action></reference>');
            $layout->generateXml();
        endif;
    }
    return $this;
}
```